# property of the class in null while the database contains it

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have these two models:

```
public class SystemGroup
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual SystemGroup ParentGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SystemGroup> SubGroups { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SystemGroupItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class SystemGroupItem
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SystemGroup Group { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Person> AppliedPersons { get; set; }
}
```

the problem is in this code

```
YarigaranDbContext context = new YarigaranDbContext();
SystemGroupItem i = context.SystemGroupItems.First();
return View(Items);
```

`i.Group` is `null` while I have it in my Database:

[image: screenshot of table in database]

I'm using EF version 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your property is `virtual`.